# Arrangement of integers 1..k^2 in k*k grid to minimize energy function

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, computer-science

Question arises from considering cache oblivious algorithms.

What is the optimal way arrange the numbers $1$ to $k^2$ in a grid, to minimize to average difference between any two neighbouring squares?  What about minimizing the expected maximum difference between two squares, chosen uniformly?  [Joining the edges of the grid to form a torus]

We can do better than just filling in row by row, for instance the Morton layout (for $k = 2^n$), as illustrated below for $k = 16$

$\begin{array}{cccccccc} 1&  2&  5&  6& 17& 18& 21& 22\\\\
 3&  4&  7&  8& 19& 20& 23& 24\\\\
 9& 10& 13& 14& 25& 26& 29& 30\\\\
11& 12& 15& 16& 27& 28& 31& 32\\\\
33& 34& 37& 38& 49& 50& 53& 54\\\\
35& 36& 39& 40& 51& 52& 55& 56\\\\
41& 42& 45& 46& 57& 58& 61& 62\\\\
43& 44& 47& 48& 59& 60& 63& 64\end{array}$

Is there a better layout?  I'm sure someone must have thought about this before, but can't seem to find anything relevant.

Comment: could you define "neighbouring" more precisely? 

Comment: What is "the expected maximum difference between two" random cells in your example?

Comment: Note that for $k=2^n$, the "filling in row by row" yields exactly the same average difference as for the Morton layout, viz. $(k+1)/2$. (assuming you mean horizontal and vertical neighbors only). So after all, I'd think there is no better arrangement than "filling in row by row" for the non-torus case.

Comment: Solve it by brute force programs from 2 by 2 to 4 by 4, maybe higher, and see what you have. For the torus insist on 1 at upper left, such further restrictions as cut down on essentially identical answers. Any cyclic permutation of rows, or of columns, changes nothing in that problem. 

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but too long for a comment. It is a heuristical argument that $\frac{k+1}2$ should be best possible.

It is easy to see that for an optimal arrangement, $1$ and $k^2$ must both occupy corners. Supposing opposite corners, consider the (monotone) lattice paths between them. Each path covers $2(k-1)$ of the differences we are looking for, so the average difference of those is at least $\frac{k^2-1}{2(k-1)}=\frac{k+1}2$ for each such path (equal if the numbers on the path are strictly increasing, greater otherwise).

This is not a proof because summing over all those paths, the differences are not counted equally often. But maybe it can be made into a proof. Problem: if the corners of $1$ and $k^2$ are *not* opposite, such an argument won't work.

The torus case seems harder, it looks like optimal constuctions may be different for even and odd $k$.

Comment: For the torus, the filling in by rows also yields the same average $\frac{k^2-1}k$ as, for $k=2^n$, the Morton layout! 